# How to have two different sort orders within the same list?

Tags: python, sorting

I have a sorted list such as

```
[[1, 'start'], [13, 'start'], [13, 'end'], [15, 'end']]
```

which is the output of `my_list.sort(key=lambda x: x[0])`. However, if there is a tie with the 0th element of each sub-list, as is the case with the middle two elements, then I need the sort to have the lists with `end` come first. So the desired output would be

```
[[1, 'start'], [13, 'end'], [13, 'start'], [15, 'end']]
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html

Comment: `sorted(my_list)` is sufficient here (try it yourself). It works because `end` is before `start` alphabetically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it sorting by another element, a `boolean`, indicating whether or not the second element is `end`:

```
my_list.sort(key=lambda x: (x[0], x[1] != 'end'))
[[1, 'start'], [13, 'end'], [13, 'start'], [15, 'end']]
```

This will be using the following list of tuples in order to sort the list:

```
[(x[0], x[1] != 'end') for x in my_list]
[(1, True), (13, True), (13, False), (15, False)]
```

Where the second element will be `False` if it is not `end` in `my_list`. Now sorting this array will yield the expected result, given that `False` i.e. `(0)` will come before `True` `(1)` when the first elements match:

```
sorted([(x[0], x[1] != 'end') for x in my_list])
[(1, True), (13, False), (13, True), (15, False)]
```

---

As @jpp points out you could simply sort by the second element lexicographically in this case:

```
my_list.sort()
[[1, 'start'], [13, 'end'], [13, 'start'], [15, 'end']]
```

Comment: Can you explain how the tuple in the lambda works?

Comment: In the case where you only have `start` and `end`, `(x[0], x[1])` is sufficient.

Comment: Yes good point @jpp lexicographic order is good enough here

Comment: @yatu I think you have a mistake in your example. Shouldn't the output of `[(x[0], x[1] != 'end') for x in my_list]` be `[(1, True), (13, False), (13, False), (15, False)]`?

Comment: No,  you can check it yourself, it gives  the mentioned output which is then used to sort

Comment: Oh oops ><. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
my_list.sort(key = lambda x:(x[0],x[1]))
```

Comment: `key=lambda x: (x[0], x[1])` is redundant.